# Emscripten Unresolved Symbol warning/error

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio, sdl, emscripten

I have successfully compiled my C++ game with Emscripten, however, the compiler outputs two warnings:

`warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN4MainC1Eiiii
 warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN4Main8gameLoopEv`

Main is a class that I wrote, and gameLoop is a function in Main.

Does anyone here know what causes these errors or how to fix them?

I compiled my game by opening the Emscripten Command Prompt bat file, and typing

`emscripten\1.12.0\em++ path_to_my_game -o path_to_my_output_file.html`

When I open the html file in Firefox, all I see is a black rectangle with -1 written inside of it.

My game uses the SDL2 libraries, but I know that Emscripten has successfully compiled games that use SDL. Are there some SDL functions that don't work with Emscripten or something?
Keep in mind, I had no compiler errors, and the only compiler warning I got besides the ones I already showed had to do with a 'meaningless' struct declaration that was in another class. I believe the exact highlighted code was:

`typedef struct Point;`

Thanks for any help

Edit: Upon trying to compile other parts of code such as the Splash Screen and the Main Menu, I get more interesting results.
Here are my warnings:

`warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN17TimedSplashScreenC1ENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS011char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEiii
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN17TimedSplashScreenD1Ev
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN8MainMenuC1Eii
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN8MainMenu8menuLoopEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN8MainMenuD1Ev
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN4MainC1Eiiii
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN4Main8gameLoopEv`

The next part only comes out when I don't run the splash screen or the main menu:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_32bit\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 268, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
...
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`

The '...' replaces a bunch of other similar looking messages, there are lots of `_subprocess.TerminateProcess`

Keep in mind once again, I have run this code perfectly in Visual Studio, the Splash Screen and the Main Menu are both perfectly functional (so is the rest of the game).

Comment: Are you sure that gameLoop was defined correctly? This sort of link error tends to occur when you declare and use a function, but never define it properly.  One guess is that either you forgot the Main:: before the name in the function's definition, or else you missed some other namespace information.

Comment: Just checked, and yes it was defined correctly (as far as I know). I'm writing my code in Visual Studio, so if it wasn't defined properly I would probably see some sort of error, or my code wouldn't run